# JavaScript deviceorientation on Microsoft Surface Pro 2: alpha and gamma values switched

Tags: javascript, ios, gyroscope, device-orientation

I am using the `deviceorientation` event in JavaScript to retrieve Gyroscope data. So far, I have tested this on iOS devices which worked perfectly. Today I tried the same code on a Microsoft Surface Pro 2 tablet running Chrome 39 and noticed I get pretty strange values.

After exploring this a bit, it seems that the alpha and gamma values are switched on the Surface Pro, as it can be seen when testing on [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/deviceorientationsample.html).

When lying flat on a table and rotating the device, my iPad Air changes its alpha value while the Surface Pro changes the gamma value. When picking up the device (so it stands at a 90 degree angle to the table), I get a gamma value of 90 on the iPad and an alpha value of 90 on the Surface Pro.

I suppose, according to the description given at [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/) about how those events should be working, the iPad is doing the correct thing but the Surface Pro is not.

So I guess my question is: Is this a known issue? Is there any way to detect or work around this?

**WORKAROUND**:

I am currently using the following workaround for this:

```
var alphaGammaFlipped = false;
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(e) {
    if (e.alpha < 0 || e.gamma > 180) alphaGammaFlipped = true;

    var alpha = e.alpha;
    var beta  = e.beta;
    var gamma = e.gamma;
    if (alphaGammaFlipped) {
        var temp = alpha;
        alpha = gamma;
        gamma = temp;
    }

    // Do something with alpha, beta, gamma...
});
```

This code uses the assumption that alpha should be between 0 and 360 and gamma should be between -180 and 180. If one of them is out of bounds, this means that they are probably flipped. Obviously, this is just a workaround als also the values will be wrong as long as both stay between 0 and 180. If anyone has something better, I'd be glad.

Comment: not sure if in the same way, but the values vary from iOS to android as well...

Comment: I don't have an android device nearby so I can't say, but I can test next week and report back

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with the same config (Surface Pro 2 + javascript `deviceorientation`), **the three angles are reversed**.

For fix this I do that :

```
false_alpha  =  gamma
false_beta   =  alpha
false_gamma  =  beta
```

(I noticed that there was no inversion with Internet Explorer 11 ...)